# How do I turn this radio button javascript to a link activated javascript

Tags: javascript

Just as the title says, I have this javascript that is currently being controlled by radio buttons but I want it changed to be controlled by a hyperlink

Javascript:

```
   function Init()
   {
        document.role_form.reset();
        document.host_form.reset();
        document.guest_form.reset();

       //MBR Code: Use querystring to initialize the form
       var sRole = GetQueryString()["role"];
       if (sRole) {
            SelectRole(sRole)
            if (sRole != '')
            {
                document.role_form.role[0].checked = sRole.toLowerCase() == 'host';
                document.role_form.role[1].checked = sRole.toLowerCase() == 'guest';
            }

       }
```

current HTML form (Radio buttons):

```
    <form name="role_form">
<p align="center" style="FONT-SIZE:12px; COLOR:#000000; TEXT-ALIGN:center">
<input name="role" id="role" type="radio" value="host" onClick="SelectRole('host')">
<span class="blackbodymain ">Host&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input name="role"  id="role" type="radio" value="guest" onClick="SelectRole('guest')">
<span class="blackbodymain ">Participant </span></p>
 </form>
```

And how I want to control it:

```
<ul id="loginmenu">
            <li class="active"><a href="#host" onClick="SelectRole('host')">Host</a></li>
            <li><a href="#participant" onClick="SelectRole('guest')">Participant</a></li>

        </ul>
```

Comment: Can't tell what you're asking.  Can you clarify or add more explanation?

Comment: I'm asking on how to modify the above javascript code to associate with links instead of radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem has something to do with what is returned from selectRole.  I don't know because I can't see it, but link wont happen if the function returns false (or something evaluated to false)

```
 <li class="active"><a href="#host" onclick=selectAndGo('host')">Host</a></li>
 <li><a href="#guest' onclick='selectAndGo('guest')">Participant</a></li>
```

And in the javascript

```
 function selectAndGo(arg)
 {
      selectRole(arg);
      return true;
}
```

Comment: the link has to stay as is because it is also controlling another effect so it has to remain as the following:  <a href="#host">

Comment: by 'another effect' you just mean going to the element with that id, right?  the function captures that.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Something about init that doesnt do what you intend?  your code seems (at least mostly) correct.  I pin the error on selectRole bc its the only thing I cant see.

Comment: it controls a jQuery tabs effect, I just tried your example but it didn't work in my circumstance.

Comment: you have to share what "works" and "doesn't work" mean 'in your circumstance' in order for anyone to help you

Comment: There really is no problem with the code itself at its current state but i'm changing the look of the site and need to get away from the radio buttons and replace them with hyperlinks instead.

Comment: Well when I tried the example above, the jQuery tabs ceased to work b/c the #host was not present in the hyperlink and the function itself did not take me where I needed to go.  You'll have to forgive me as I am primarily a graphic designer and have very limited knowledge at the moment about Javascript

Comment: sounds like you need to set id's or class's somewhere so the jQuery selector can find what it needs